# Let $\alpha\geq 1$, let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and assume that $\|b\|\leq \|a\|$. Show that $\|a-b\|\leq \|\alpha a-b\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $\alpha\geq 1$, let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and assume that $\|b\|\leq \|a\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the 2-norm. Show that 
\begin{align}\|a-b\|\leq \|\alpha a-b\|.\end{align}

I can see this geometrically, but not sure how to show it algebraically. Any hint is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.* $\|\alpha a-b\|^2-\|a-b\|^2=\langle\alpha a-b,\,\alpha a-b\rangle-\langle a-b,\,a-b\rangle=(\alpha-1)\left[(\alpha+1)\|a\|^2-2\langle a,b\rangle\right]$.